# How to make an electron app with the ability to offline and online (sync data)?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm new to electron, pouchdb, couchdb and also stackoverflow...I have a project where I need to make a desktop app with the ability to work online and offline. In other words, when user with different platforms use my app in offline mode, the data will be save in the local server and will be sync when they are online. I find that I can use pouchdb and couchdb, but the problem is when I try my electron app in different machine, the database in couchdb didnt update. I found that couchdb is a remote database then I try IBM cloudant and it also didn't update. Is there any way how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us code that you attempted? Are you replicating your local pouchdb with your remote couchdb database?

Comment: @AlexisCôté I think I already figure out how to make my app work offline and online..I follow this tutorial https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html and I'm using cloudant instead of remote couchdb :)

Comment: Solve what? You haven't described a problem, or shown us any code.